# Check different ZIP-Code ranges within a specific input field and do something based on that

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need a script which checks different ZIP-Code ranges within a field with the id "zip" and based of that range, it should insert a specific mail address into another input field with the id "mail".

For example:

```
<input id="zip" value="72365">
<input id="mail" value="7000-8000@mail.com">
```

Ranges:
If between 0 and 59999
 insert first@mail.de
If between 60000 and 72999
insert second@mail.de
If between 73000 and 76999
insert third@mail.de

It should be checked and inserted "live" while the ZIP-Code is typed into the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Far i understand as per your question You Can try Like this

```js
$("#zip").change(function(){

  var zip = $(this).val();

  if(zip > 59999){
    $("#mail").val("first@mail.de");
  }else if(zip > 60000){
    $("#mail").val("second@mail.de");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="zip" type="text">
<input id="mail" type="text">
```

*Maybe the values will be wrong but this is just for demonstration*

Comment: if(zip < 59999){..}else if(zip > 60000){.....}else if(zip > 73000){.....}else{....}. if this can solve your problem mark this as answer and if useful you can upvote.